# Remove duplicate character strings from list column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
structure(list(class = c("Großbrittanien", "Rest Europa"), countries = list(
    c("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"), "Spain")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

it looks like this:
[image]

I want to turn the `countries`-list column into a character column. I want to remove duplicate entries. Such that United Kingdom only appears once. I am a little confused how I could, using the dplyr syntax, achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or without `unnest`, using `unique` by class, before converting to a character string.

**With grouping:**

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(countries = toString(unique(unlist(countries))), .by = class)

# Note: If you're using `dplyr < v.1.1.0`, use `group_by`/`ungroup`.
```

**With `purrr`:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df |>
  mutate(countries = map_chr(countries, ~ toString(unique(.))))
```

**Output:**

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  class          countries     
  <chr>          <chr>         
1 Großbrittanien United Kingdom
2 Rest Europa    Spain, Portugal
```

**Data (including something that is not duplicated .. Portugal):**

```r
df <- 
  structure(list(class = c("Großbrittanien", "Rest Europa"), countries = list(
    c("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"), c("Spain", "Portugal"))), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                    -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can unnest `countries` and then remove duplicated rows.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  unnest(countries) %>%
  distinct()

# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   class          countries     
#   <chr>          <chr>         
# 1 Großbrittanien United Kingdom
# 2 Rest Europa    Spain
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version using `dplyr` syntax

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  unnest(countries) %>%
  distinct(class, countries) %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarise(countries = paste(countries, collapse = ", "))
```

Comment: `unnest` is from `tidyr`